# How to stop displaying the Id without losing the functionality

Tags: customization, user-roles, code

I am using a custom code to make certain plugin's functionality available only with particular capabilities.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
// Check if User can Edit
// Set permission to false = 'not allowed'
$current_user_is_allowed_to_edit = false;
// Get the ID of the user who watches this post
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
// Get the ID of the Post-Writer
$post_author_ID = the_author_meta('ID');

//   Check if User has role 'Editor' and higher  OR is the Post-Writer
if ( current_user_can('edit_others_posts') ||  get_post(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'post_id'))->post_author == get_current_user_id() ) {

    // Set permission to true = 'allowed'
    $current_user_is_allowed_to_edit = true;
}
?>
```

I want `$post_author_ID = the_author_meta('ID');` only to set the capability to access particular content `{ live_edit('post_title, myfield2'); }` and not to publish the id. But it publishes some number on every post which I don't want. Here is the [complate template](http://pastebin.com/GEUCebBi)

Also let me know If I am not using the correct way to restrict access to particular content- `{ live_edit('post_title, myfield2'); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`the_author_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta) *displays* the data. That is, it `echo`s the data to the screen. From the Codex entry for that function:

> NOTE: Use `get_the_author_meta()` if you need to return (not display)
>   the information.

So, use [`get_the_author_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta) instead.

There is a somewhat reliable pattern in WordPress function naming whereby functions starting with `the_` `echo` data to the screen; functions starting with `get_` return the data.